# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '([Int])'

Tags: swift, timestamp

I'm converting the timestamp to normal type but I'm getting this error --- Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '([Int])', How to fix it?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)
    //print jobTime = 1504753200
    let unixTimestamp = Double(jobTime) //error here
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(jobTime[indexPath.row])-\(jobEndTime[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}
```

I'm retrieving the JSON data and put into table view cell

```
var jobTime = [Int]()
var jobEndTime = [Int]()
```

viewDidLoad

```
guard let jobs = json["jobs"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return }

for job in jobs {
    if let id = job["jobTime"] as? Int{
       self.jobTime.append(id)
    }
    if let id = job["jobEndTime"] as? Int{
       elf.jobEndTime.append(id)
    }
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)
    //print jobTime = 1504753200
    let unixTimestamp = Double(jobTime[indexPath.row]) //Change here
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(jobTime[indexPath.row])-\(jobEndTime[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}
```